# Problem when factoring operators

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, solution-verification, fake-proofs

So I was trying to find a general solution to the second-order linear differential equation: $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+p(x)y=0$$I had read about factoring operators as if they were polynomials. So, I wrote the DE as $$(D^2+p(x))y=0\implies(D+i\sqrt{p(x)})(D-i\sqrt{p(x)})y=0$$So we have that either $$(D+i\sqrt{p(x)})y=0\text{ or }(D-i\sqrt{p(x)})y=0$$Which are first order linear differential equations that are quite trivial to solve. However, the solution to each of these combined is $y=e^{\pm i\int\sqrt{p(x)}dx}$, which is not a solution to the original DE. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: $[D,\sqrt{p(x)}]\neq 0$ in general, so $(D+i\sqrt{p(x)})(D-i\sqrt{p(x)})=D^2+p(x)-i[D,\sqrt{p(x)}]\neq D^2+p(x)$.

Comment: Your trick works with linear DE with constant coefficients.

Comment: @user577215664 So why doesn't it work with variable coefficients, user[insert first nine digits of Euler-Mascheroni constant here]?

Comment: You can factorise only some DE like DE with connstant coefficients and it also works with Euler-Cauchy's differential DE but in the general case it doesn't work and you have to pay attention to the fact  that the operator D doesn't commute so $pD \ne Dp$ when p is not constant @KamalSaleh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $D$ doesn't commute in general:
$$p(x)D \ne Dp(x)$$
Because;
$$Dp(x)y=p'(x)y+p(x)y'\ne p(x)y'=p(x)Dy$$
But when $p$ is constant we have:
$$pD = Dp$$